# Creating a style-array automatically from an existing worksheet using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is there a way to create a `$styleArray` automatically from a existing Excel worksheet using PHPExcel?

Something like:

```
$styleArray = $file->getSheetByName('XY')->getStyles()->
copyAllStylesInRangeAndCreateStyleArray($range);
```

So I could use this generated style array with

```
$file->getSheetByName('AB')->getStyle($range)->
applyFromArray($styleArray)`
```

to copy the style to another sheet (even in another workbook) or save the information in an extra e.g. Config-File.

Or do I have to find a way using `duplicateStyle()` and go through every cell (compare [Styling cells](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/286662))?

Comment: Maybe it's even better to just use the `addExternalSheet()` functionality?

Comment: Afraid not.... I've looked at coding a function to generate a style array from an individual cell styling, but never at building a set of style arrays for a complete worksheet